# Quickly search through a numpy array and sum the corresponding values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, search

I have an array with around 160k entries which I get from a CSV-file and it looks like this:

```
data_arr = np.array(['ID0524', 1.0]
                    ['ID0965', 2.5]
                     .
                     .
                    ['ID0524', 6.7]
                    ['ID0324', 3.0])
```

I now get around 3k unique ID's from some database and what I have to do is look up each of these IDs in the array and sum the corresponding numbers.
So if I would need to look up "ID0524", the sum would be 7.7.

My current working code looks something like this (I'm sorry that it's pretty ugly, I'm very new to numpy):

```
def sumValues(self, id)
    sub_arr = data_arr[data_arr[0:data_arr.size, 0] == id]

    sum_arr = sub_arr[0:sub_arr.size, 1]
    return sum_arr.sum()
```

And it takes around ~18s to do this for all 3k IDs.

I wondered if there is probably any faster way to this as the current runtime seems a bit too long for me. I would appreciate any guidance and hints on this. Thank you!

Comment: what about iterating through the list and save the results in a dictionary? i.e. for each key create a dict entry, each time you see this key, add the corresponding value

Comment: First, what's the array dtype?  Second, numpy doesn't do this very well.  `unique` depends on sorting, which puts like values next to each other. Third, Python `default_dict` can make collecting like ids quite easy

Answer (score 0):

You could try the using builtin [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/index.html) methods.

[numpy.intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html#numpy.intersect1d) to find the unique IDs
[numpy.sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html?highlight=sum#numpy.sum) to sum them up

Answer (score 0):

A convenient tool to do your task is *Pandas*, with its grouping mechanism.

Start from the necessary import:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then convert *data_arr* to a pandasonic DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': data_arr[:, 0], 'Amount': data_arr[:, 1].astype(float)})
```

The reason for some complication in the above code is that:

- elements of your input array are of a **single** type (in this case
  *object*),
- so there is necessary to convert the second column to *float*.

Then you can get the expected result in a **single** instruction:

```
result = df.groupby('Id').sum()
```

The result, for your data sample, is:

```
        Amount
Id            
ID0324     3.0
ID0524     7.7
ID0965     2.5
```

Another approach is that you could read your CSV file **directly**
into a DataFrame (see *read_csv* method), so there is no need to use
any *Numpy* array.

The advantage is that *read_csv* is clever enough to recognize the data
type of each column separately, at least it is able to tell apart numbers
from strings.